# Localhost not showing views

Tags: python, django

I am making a django app for storing files and I'm not seeing any errors on the runserver console but when I decide to go to localhost I get this error.[Screenshot of localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrR4j.png)

Which is odd because my urls.py is structured like this.

```
    urlpatterns = [
         url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
         url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
         url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', document, name='document')
    ]
```

And my models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
case_number = models.IntegerField()
description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
lawyer_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
case = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Another app[Page not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wt8d.png)

and the code from urls.py on the app

```
     urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),
    url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      ]
```

and the models.py

```
class Board(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Topic(models.Model):
subject = models.CharField(max_length=250)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics')
starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics')


class Post(models.Model):
message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='+')
```

I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6.2

Comment: where is catalog url?? i cant find any urlpattern with that name,

Comment: exactly, that's my problem.

Comment: if you dont define a catalog url then how are you suppose to get it, it will show 404 if a urlpattern doesnt match, define a url with catalog and attach the view you are supposed to see

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the 404 was raised by the `info.views.document` view, which you haven't shown.

You are trying to go to `/catalog/`, so presumably the view is trying to fetch a document with `slug="catalog"`. If you don't have a document with that slug, then the 404 is expected behaviour.

For the second url patterns, you have not defined any URL patterns to match `/catalog/`, so the 404 is the expected behaviour again. You haven't said what view you want to handle that URL, so we can't give any more help.